# How to terminate a process but also call __exit__()?

Tags: python, exit

In my program I call a class with an `__exit__()` method as an process from `from multiprocessing import Process`. When there is an error in the main program, I do `myprocess.terminate()`, but this does not call the `__exit__()` method.

How can I terminate the process but also call the `__exit__`?

---

Addition:
I have 2 processes and I want to exit bouth of them when 1 is termnated by an `sys.exit()`.
Here is my way to do it right now. From within the 1th process I call `sys.exit()`, witch "deactivates the process". In the main process I have a loop that looks like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        None
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        accelerationrecorder1_process.terminate()
        datasaver_process.terminate()
        sys.exit()
    try:
        if datasaver_process.is_alive() == False:
            accelerationrecorder1_process.terminate()
            sys.exit()
    except:
        sys.exit()

    try:
        if accelerationrecorder1_process.is_alive() == False:
            datasaver_process.terminate()

            sys.exit()
    except:
        sys.exit()
```

But if I call the `sys.exit()` in a process the other process doesnt execute the **exit**

Comment: If you use `multiprocessing.Process`, you don't have a thread, you have a separate process. Show your code, please.

Comment: Also, because it _is_ a separate process, you can call `terminate()` on it. Threads in Python can't be stopped from outside them; the usual pattern is to have a loop in a secondary thread that checks a `threading.Event()` for whether it should stop; an event/signal could work in your case too.

Comment: Hey AKX, my code is really long and I would prefere to not publish everything. Sorry for the mistake i ment process not threat. I will include my solution (now working)

Answer (score 0):

`__exit__` magic method is not what you think it is. It is not meant to be called before your program quit, but before you leave a with block. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/) for more details about that.

Basically, you can't have a method that is automatically called when you process terminates. You have to call it manually. But this is still feasible. Somewhere, presumably in your main function, you could put a try statement in order to catch any exception thrown by any part of your application (note that `sys.exit()` raises an `SystemExit` exception that will be caught like other exceptions), and add a finally clause to the try block in which you call every method that is required whenever your program terminates. Example:

```
def main():
  try:
    do_thing()
  except:
    log_error()
  finally:
    call_methods()
```

Remember to implement a `log_error` function (or use any existing), or debugging will be harsh.